# Setting div to rest of available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div and 2 child divs (child-left and child-right).  child-right div will contain 1 or 2 icons depending on dynamic page requirement. The child-left div contains the title and also used as a handle to drag operation. I do not want to set a width px or % (like the 90% I have below). How do I set the child-left div to take the rest of available space after what is occupied by child-right.

```
<div id="parent"> 
    <div id="child-left" style="width:90%"> 
        This is my title
    </div>
    <div id="child-right"> 
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your css also, or better yet make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). The css can effect the answer slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should help you:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child-right">Hey</div>
    <div id="child-left">This is my title</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#child-left {
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#child-right {
    float:right;
    border-style:solid;
}
#parent {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hdx9K/)

Comment: Very good thank you! I guess the key here is to define the child-right  so it renders before the child-left....Awesome!